# Why does the recursive call print '123456' instead of '1'?

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble understanding how the code is able to recover the remaining integers after they are taken off the original value via x/10. Is there something going on behind the scenes?

```
// precondition: x >= 0
// Question: What is printed from method call mystery(123456)?

public void mystery(int x) {
    if ((x/10) != 0) {
        mystery(x/10);
    }
    System.out.print(x % 10);
}
```

Comment: I suggest working this out on paper, or debugging to see what is going on "under the hood" so to speak. Here's a hint: there is a print statement in the method, so every recursive call will print one thing

Comment: Try to do a bit of **research**, e.g. a *web search* for [`recursion explained`](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion+explained)

Comment: does it have something to do with "adding values to a stack"?

Comment: What is the initial call to the function `mystery()`? For instance is it `mystery(654321);` or `mystery(123456);`?

Comment: @RichardChambers from the question title, it seems the initial call is mystery(123456);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each invocation of mystery creates a new stack frame in the JVM. These frames are used to store parameters, local variables, and other data which I'll omit for brevity. In your recursive step (mystery(x / 10)), each newly created stack frame will be holding a successively smaller ***copy*** of the result of x / 10. Once the base case is reached, each stack frame will then print the value of its ***copy*** of x % 10.

So, for example, mystery(123456):

- Frame 1: 123456
- Frame 2: 12345
- Frame 3: 1234
- Frame 4: 123
- Frame 5: 12
- Frame 6: 1 (Base case is reached! Each frame will now print and return)

Modulo 10 will always print the rightmost digit. So that means after all the frames are finished, you will be left with 123456. If you are expecting 1, then how might you go about modifying your solution? (Hint: think about base cases!)

Comment: Thanks! Would it make a difference if the mystery parameter was a reference type like String instead of a primitive type?

Comment: @HelloLuna Yes! I understand what you're asking, but for the record Strings are immutable. However if x were a field of an mutable object, doing something like Obj.x = Obj.x / 10 would indeed be seen by all stack frames (assuming they print Obj.x after all recursive calls). In the above example, we'd get out 111111.

Answer (score 0):

Each recursive call to mystery() happens before the final print statement that prints the digit. The current state of the program is saved to the stack before the function begins to execute again, so on the last execution of the function, when x/10 = 0, the 1 is printed. Then the program returns to the previous execution of the function, where x = 12, and continues to that print statement to print 12 % 10 = 2. This continues the same way until the program reaches the top level execution of the function.

[This page](http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~freedman/241/241notes/241recur.htm) explains recursion and has a useful diagram for the factorial example that shows how functions are called and returned.